# Why use while(true) with .take with a blockingcollection?

Tags: c#, while-loop, blockingcollection, take

I have been looking into using blockingcollection. I found [this article](https://www.simplethread.com/blockingcollection-and-iproducerconsumercollection/) very helpful

Although, he is using "tasks" for multi threading purposes, I don't think I need this. But anyways, the author demonstrate 2 ways to iterate through the collection to remove items. The first way:

```
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Worker 2: " + blockingCollection.Take());
}
```

And the second way:

```
foreach (string value in blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Worker 1: " + value);
}
```

The author explains that the second way is more elegant so I plan to use the second way. However, just for my understanding. Can someone explain to me the while(true) loop in the first technique? I don't understand, I have been reading the Microsoft docs and google... But haven't found anything that would indicate that ".Take()" returns true or false under any circumstances...

Comment: "But haven't found anything that would indicate that ".Take()" returns true or false under any circumstances..." I don't understand why that code makes you think it *should* return true or false. It's not `while (...Take())` - it's just `while (true)`, i.e. "loop forever".

Comment: Wow... I guess that was a super newbie question... Thank you!!

Comment: BTW a better alternative would be to use [Channels](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/)

Comment: It can throw either of them @sommmen, according to the docs - the key issue here is that the former code (`Take` inside an infinite loop) will throw exceptions in mainstream scenarios that the latter code (`foreach` over `GetConsumingEnumerable`) will not. I will remove my earlier comments in case they caused you offence and leave you two code paths to try - https://dotnetfiddle.net/LDxA57 Comment and uncomment the two techniques and see the difference.

Comment: The first comment at the blog post explains why you shouldn't use the `while` loop @XCELLGUY - https://www.simplethread.com/blockingcollection-and-iproducerconsumercollection/#comment-2600 Code example at https://dotnetfiddle.net/LDxA57